Как поменять цвет QMessageBox?
Как поменять цвет в QMessageBox? Т.е. сделать само окошко чёрным, а текст на ней белым?

Использовать QSS
 a.setStyleSheet(
                "QMessageBox {"
                "   background-color: #000000;" // Цвет фона
                "   color: #ffffff;" // Цвет текста
                "}"
                "QPushButton {"
                "   background-color: #0078d7;" // Цвет фона кнопки
                "   color: black;" // Цвет текста кнопки
                "   border: none;"
                "   padding: 5px 10px;"
                "}"
                "QPushButton:hover {"
                "   background-color: #0056a3;" // Цвет фона кнопки при наведении "}"
            );

Это как пример, вместо a, пишете название вашего QApplication.
